# Jquery not running before page reload

Tags: jquery

I have a *Div* with *id = refresh*

In same *Div* I have a *PHP* code that validate a condition :

```
<?php

    if (true)
    {
        // Show "checkbox" with "id = box"
    }
    else
    {
        // Hide "checkbox" with "id = box"
        // Do something to validate condition, I do it using Jquery and Ajax Call to a PHP Script, in success return I reload the "Div" with "id = refresh", everything work fine and PHP code in "Div" with "id = refresh" show that condition in true and show the "checkbox" with "id = box"
    }

?>
```

After that I would run a jquery script when checkbox is checked or unchecked, but this is not working !

But when I reload the page, if the PHP condition in *Div* with *id = refresh* is true, the Jquery script will work fine.

I can't understand why this page need to be reloaded !

**As Requested**

```
$ (document).ready (function ()
{
    // Check If Checkbox Checked
    $ ("#box").click (function ()
    {
        if ($ (this).is (":checked"))
        {
            $ ("#form").show ();
        }
        else
        {
             $ ("#form").hide ();
        }
    });
});
```

**This work correctly after page reload !**

Comment: add your jquery code for change checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your js code to :

```
$ (document).ready (function ()
{
    // Check If Checkbox Checked
    $(document).on('change', '#box', function(){
        if ($ (this).is (":checked"))
        {
            $ ("#form").show ();
        }
        else
        {
             $ ("#form").hide ();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Perfect :) This is working :p THX :) Can u just please tell me what is the different between 2 codes ? :) Thank you. @Thorin

Comment: actually the div 'box' is loaded after page loaded by ajax as you said in question so jquery will not bind directly its events,m if you need events of an element which is update/added by ajax then should bind with document or its parent which is loaded with page loadm, I hope you understand

Comment: you can upvote, if you can if the solution is working for you

Comment: Yes that was clear :) THX Again, sadly I can't up vote because of my Actual limits on this site ! @Thorin